# Haskell - What does the type Ord a mean?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm creating a merge sort function in Haskell that is recursive. I have been told as part of my assessment that I must define the type as:

```
isort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
```

I assumed the function expects an array as input and outputs an array. I know that `ord` is a class.

In the context above what does the `Ord a` mean?

This is my function:

```
isort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
isort [x] = [x]
isort (x:xs) = insert x (isort xs)
    where
        insert :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
        insert a [] = []
        insert a (b:c) | a < b      = a:b:c
                       | otherwise  = b : insert a c
```

When I try to load my functions file into ghci I get the error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Int’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for isort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
      at LabSheet2.hs:17:10
Expected type: [a]
Actual type: [Int]
...
```

Comment: Try renaming `a` on those last three lines?

Comment: There are no arrays here. `[a]` is a *list* type.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Ord a` is a typeclass constraint that indicates your function works for any type `a`, so long as `a` is comparable (`Ord`erable). The error message you're getting is due to the conflict between your outer declaration that says it works for any `Ord a => a`, and the inner `insert` that "only" works for `Int`'s.

Comment: What would be the solution for the inner declaration?

Comment: @nonsequiter I would expect you could remove the `insert` type declaration and have it be inferred. If you want to specify it explicitly, you need to be consistent. `isort` is declared to work for *any/every* `a` that is comparable, but `insert` is declared to only work for `Int` which is one particular comparable type. `Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]` could work.

Comment: @nonsequiter Also, it appears there is a bug as the `a` (variable, not type) in the base case of `insert` is ignored and should probably be `a:[]`.